# Django: Can you tell if a related field has been prefetched without fetching it?

Tags: python, django

I was wondering if there is a way in Django to tell if a related field, specifically the "many" part of a one-to-many relationship, has been fetched via, say, `prefetch_related()` without actually fetching it?

So, as an example, let's say I have these models:

```
class Question(Model):
  """Class that represents a question."""

class Answer(Model):
  """Class the represents an answer to a question."""
  question = ForeignKey('Question', related_name='answers')
```

Normally, to get the number of answers for a question, the most efficient way to get this would be to do the following (because the Django docs state that `count()` is more efficient if you just need a count):

```
# Note: "question" is an instance of class Question.
answer_count = question.answers.count()
```

However in some cases the answers may have been fetched via a `prefetch_related()` call (or some way, such as previously having iterated through the answers). So in situations like that, it would be more efficient to do this (because we'd skip the extra count query):

```
# Answers were fetched via prefetch_related()
answer_count = len(question.answers.all())
```

So what I really want to do is something like:

```
if question.answers_have_been_prefetched:  # Does this exist?
  answer_count = len(question.answers.all())
else:
  answer_count = question.answers.count()
```

I'm using Django 1.4 if it matters.  Thanks in advance.

Edit: added clarification that `prefetch_related()` isn't the only way the answers could've been fetched.

Comment: The whole point of using a wrapper library here is so that you don't, in fact, have to worry about things like this. Unless you have measured this to be a real bottleneck, just use the straightforward method and don't add unneeded complexity.

However, after a little poking in the Django source code, I have found some hints. If you still insist on trying this hack, you might try `obj._prefetched_objects_cache`, or alternatively, you might just try `print dir(question.answers)` and see if you see any cache-related looking parameters in there.

Comment: It isn't a gigantic bottleneck, no.  I was just trying to really optimize the hell out of the app and bring the number of queries down to a bear minimum.  Agreed that if the only way is hacky, then it isn't worth it.

I should clarify: prefetch_related was just an example. The results could've been fetched in some other way as well (e.g. iterating over question.answers previously in the code), which is why I was hoping for some general solution.

Comment: It would be really nice if Django could let you opt for automatic in-memory filtering of prefetched relations, so that you don't generate a new query simply by using their DSL to investigate the data you already have.

Comment: Note that the 'one' side of a relationship is stored in obj._{{field_name}}_cache

Comment: Automatic in-memory filtering would be sweeet, though is less necessary with advent of Prefetch objects.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, Django stores the prefetched results in the `_prefetched_objects_cache` attribute of the parent model instance.

So you can do something like:

```
instance = Parent.objects.prefetch_related('children').all()[0]

try:
    instance._prefetched_objects_cache[instance.children.prefetch_cache_name]
    # Ok, it's pefetched
    child_count = len(instance.children.all())
except (AttributeError, KeyError):
    # Not prefetched
    child_count = instance.children.count()
```

See the [relevant use](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L555) in the django source trunk or [the equivalent](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.9/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L562) in v1.4.9

Comment: Thanks for this, but I should clarify: prefetch_related was just an example.  The results could've been fetched in some other way as well (e.g. iterating over question.answers previously in the code).

Comment: Related manager accesses are usually not cached, you'd likely have to implement your own memoization wrapper: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/#understand-queryset-evaluation

Comment: Ah, ok, that's good to know.  So they only get cached when you use prefetch_related.  Thanks for the clarification.  Sounds like this hack isn't worth the effort and I should just do count(), but you gave me the info I needed.

Comment: It might be a good idea to put the `Ok, it's prefetched` code into `else` block of [`try … except … else`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement).

Comment: Does prefetched GenericForeignKey also gets stored in that variable?

Comment: Great, thanks. I needed this for my unittests