# Django QuerySet's _prefetched_objects_cache is empty when using the to_attr argument of Prefetch()

Tags: django

I'm writing tests to check that a Django QuerySet is prefetching what it should be. I can do this by checking the contents of an object's `_prefetched_objects_cache` property ([via this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19651840/250962)). But it doesn't work if I use the `to_attr` argument of `Prefetch()`.

Here's a simplified example that populates the cache, not using `to_attr`:

```py
books = Book.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "authors",
        queryset=Author.objects.filter(author_type="MAIN"), 
    )
).all()
```

I can then check the contents of `_prefetched_objects_cache` on an object in the QuerySet:

```
>>> print(books[0]._prefetched_objects_cache)
{'authors': <QuerySet [<Author: Author (ID #1)>]>}
```

However, if I use the `to_attr` argument:

```py
books = Book.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "authors",
        queryset=Author.objects.filter(author_type="MAIN"), 
        to_attr="people"  # <-- Added this
    )
).all()
```

...then `_prefetched_objects_cache` is empty:

```
>>> print(books[0]._prefetched_objects_cache)
{}
```

Is there a way to check that this has been prefetched? Where does it go?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's as simple as

```py
hasattr(book[0], "people")
```